# Why has my QWidget stopped expanding to fit its children?

Tags: qt

Here is a screenshot of my Qt application. I have blurred everything which isn't important. Look at the bottom-right.

[image]

That "Comment" bit is a `QGroupBox` containing a `QTextEdit`, it is being cropped because some containing `QWidget` is not expanding to fit it.

So far I have seen widgets expand by default to fit their contents (as long as child widgets are added to layouts before they become visible, which is what's happening here) but suddenly this is no longer happening. If I manually expand the window, the "Comment" box is laid out as expected.

The innermost `QTextEdit` has `setMinimumHeight` called and I have verified that every widget in the hierarchy has `QSizePolicy::GrowFlag` set in its `sizePolicy`. I have grepped the source to check that I am not setting maximum sizes anywhere in the application. And, yes, the `QTextEdit` is in the layout of the `QGroupBox`.

It seems like Qt is saying "I'll automatically expand the main window to fit the contents, but only up to a limit."

Why is this happening and how do I stop it? Or rather, how do I make it continue the helpful auto-resizing behaviour regardless of the size/depth of child widgets?

Comment: You need to take into consideration your MainWindow width and height, QWidget cannot expand over that width/height size.

Comment: I'm saying the MainWindow up until now has chosen its own width and height to suit the contents, and its GrowFlag is set so it should still do so.

Comment: When you run your application and then expand the main window so that the text edit properly visible, how far can you shrink the window?

Comment: Far enough that a number of widgets get cropped. Maybe this has something to do with QSizePolicy::ShrinkFlag but the widget should only shrink if there's some "pressure" on it from a parent widget -- my question is where is this pressure coming from and how do I remove it? I don't want to change settings on ALL my child widgets when the parent can be fixed. But the parents all have GrowFlag, so I'm confused.